# Using high-definition progress circle in tablet

Tags: android, tablet, definition, progress, android-screen-support

I'm developing android app. In my GALAXY Tab 10.1 shows low-definition progress circle. However, my cell phone GALAXY Nexus shows high-definition progress circle.

At first, GALAXY Nexus also shows low-definition progress circle. So, I tried to change value of anyDensity false to true, like this:

[AndroidManifest.xml]
`<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true"
                  android:normalScreens="true"
                  android:largeScreens="true"
                  android:anyDensity="true"/>`

This code works fine on GALAXY Nexus, but doesn't on GALAXY Tab. How to display high-definition progress circle in my tablet? I'm just using default progress circle...

- Nexus:720×1280 /
- GALAXY Tab:1280×800 (150ppi)

Comment: I edited the answer, please select as accepted answe, if it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

You could override the `spinner_black_76` image which is beeing used in API level 10 in every density folder. You could get the hdpi image from :

```
android-sdk\platforms\android-10\data\res\drawable-hdpi\spinner_black_76
```

put this hdpi image in all your folders(hdpi/mdpi/ldpi).

**But** I don't know if this will work on other API levels. 
So just create your own Progress Bar with this:

```
<animated-rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_black_76"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:framesCount="12"
    android:frameDuration="100" />
```

EDIT:

Ok I looked it up. In every API Level from 7-16 the default spinner is called `spinner_black_76` so if you would put the hdpi image in all folders, it would should override it in all plattforms(at least from 7-16).